# Include landmarks in routing instructions based on OpenStreetMap data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, openstreetmap, arcgis-10.3, routing, network-dataset

I created an OSM network dataset in ArcGIS 10.3.1 with the tool from the OSM toolbox. Now I like to include landmarks within the routing instructions. If the network dataset is built with the help of the network analyst there is a tab where the landmark layer can be defined. But in the OSM tool there is no such tab.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: Found bellow link will useful for future searches for above questions. 

https://www.slideshare.net/anitagraser/landmarkbased-instructions-for-pedestrian-navigation-systems-using-osm